# Error: Class 'MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient'

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un código para probar la conexión con una api en mailchimp. Con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
    require_once('..\..\..\..\..\Users\rodri\vendor\autoload.php');

    $mailchimp = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();

    $mailchimp->setCOnfig([
            'apiKey' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
            'server' => 'YOUR_SERVER_PREFIX'
    ]);

    $response = $mailchimp->ping->get();
    print_r($response);
?>
```

Y me presenta el siguiente error.

`Error: Class 'MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient'`

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Has agregado el componente al proyecto usando `composer require mailchimp/marketing` ?

Comment: Hola. Si lo agregué.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que lo estes agregando a la carpeta `vendor` equivocada, puedes chequear ejecutando

```
composer require mailchimp/marketing
```

ejecutandolo desde de la carpeta `Users\rodri` segun lo que incluyes en tu codigo.

Ya que no usas *namespaces*, puede que tambien tenga efecto que escribas:

```
$mailchimp = new MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient(); // sin backslash al inicio
```

ademas de cambiar las mayusculas/minusculas en `setConfig`

```
$mailchimp->setConfig([ ...
```